# mthaml processing my php variables inside :javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mthaml

I'm using a PHP port of MTHAML which uses the exact same syntax. How can I tell MTHAML to not touch my variables when I use them inside

https://github.com/arnaud-lb/MtHaml

For instance this

```
  :javascript
      if (#{$response)} !== "") {
        show_error("#{$response}");
      }
```

Gets converted to this

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
      if (<?php echo htmlspecialchars(escape("$response"),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?> !== "") {
        show_error("<?php echo htmlspecialchars($response,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?>");
      }
  //]]>
  </script>
```

So my PHP boolean variables show up as blank in the rendered javascript, or if my php variable is a string with quotes, the quotes end up being converted to &quot.

Answer (score 0):

The auto escaper is not aware of the context (html, js, etc). And unfortunately you can't disable it in `#{}` interpolations.

Something you could do is to expose your php variables as html data-attributes:

```
#data(data-response=$data)
:javascript
    var response = $("#data").data("response");
    ...
```

Alternatively, switch to MtHaml/Twig instead of MtHaml/PHP. Twig auto escaper is more powerful.

```
- autoescape true js
    :javascript
        if ("#{response}") { // response is escaped in javascript mode
```